# Find all eigenvectors in matlab or in DevC

Tags: matlab, dev-c++

Now I'm working with eigenvectors and eigenvalues on Matlab.

I used `[V,D] =eigs(A)`, but it only generate 6 largest eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors!  Do you know any libraries that support finding all the eigenvectors or finding a number of eigenvectors of a matrix?

I'm also working with DevC, any suggestion with devC is also welcomed! P/s: I'm not good in english, sorry about that! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eig` instead of `eigs`

From [eig documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eig.html)

> [V,D] = eig(A) produces matrices of eigenvalues (D) and eigenvectors
>   (V) of matrix A, so that A*V = V*D. Matrix D is the canonical form of
>   A — a diagonal matrix with A's eigenvalues on the main diagonal.
>   Matrix V is the modal matrix — its columns are the eigenvectors of A.

From [eigs documentatione](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eigs.html)

> [V,D] = eigs(A) returns a diagonal matrix D of A's six largest
>   magnitude eigenvalues and a matrix V whose columns are the
>   corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really heplful!